# How to create an boost::asio::ip::address_v6 from sockaddr_in6 without making an extra copy?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The problem is that `address_v6` class accepts raw data strictly as `bytes_type` class:

```
typedef array< unsigned char, 16 > bytes_type;
```

but `sockaddr_in6` struct doesn't have that, it has C-style arrays, that can't be converted to `std::array` without copying. So I have to create an `std::array`, copy data there, and pass that array to `address_v6`, which copies data from that `std::array` to its internal buffer.

I wish I could use or implement some C-style array viewer class but I wouldn't be able to pass it to the constructor anyway, because it's not a template function.

Is there some way to create an `address_v6` without making an extra copy of the data?

Comment: Why are you concerned about copying just 16 bytes (two machine words on many modern systems)?

Comment: @DavisHerring due to my bad memory I forgot that array doesn't allocate its memory on heap, thus there's no overhead for that. So yeah it's fast anyway, but I was still curious how to avoid extra copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::array` is required to be struct that contains raw array as its first and only non-static data member. As the raw array contains `unsigned char`s it is therefore standard layout class. So I can not find a reason from standard why following code would not work:

```
auto& bytearray = reinterpret_cast<std::array<unsigned char,16>&>(ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr);
```

Replace `auto&` with plain `auto` if you want to copy.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I've tried to do a similar cast, but due to my lack of experience couldn't pull it off, had mistakes here and there. But now it works, thanks!

Comment: It’s undefined behavior to use that reference for anything.  Being standard-layout doesn’t mean you can pretend an object is there if it’s not.

Comment: @DavisHerring why is it UB? If I'm fully aware of the insides of the class, and I'm sure they correspond with the data I'm casting from, it's still UB?

Comment: @DavisHerring I do agree that std::array is specified very carefully to be bit-compatible with C-style arrays (imagine the riots from game devs, had they standardized otherwise). It should not be hard to find the authoritative section on this

Comment: @Nikita128: [basic.lval]/11 provides the spirit of the rule, but actually applies only to scalars.  [expr.static.cast]/13 describes the failure of the `reinterpret_cast` to find an appropriate object (not just type!), and then eventually [expr.ref]/6.2 or [expr.call]/2 produces undefined behavior by omission for want of an object with the given member (function).

Comment: @sehe: Bit-compatibility can help with `std::memcpy` and `std::bit_cast`, but not with `reinterpret_cast`, which (contrary to popular belief) is about objects, not bits.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` owns its memory, there's no way to create a view and pass it to std::array. And there's no need in this. Allocate std::array on a stack and do a copy, this is not expensive operation, you need you copy only 16 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, you've just reminded me that std::array has no memory allocations on heap, so there is no overhead for that. But still I wanted to figure out how to avoid extra copying.